# Forming a nasty POST request using Requests Python library

Tags: java, python, cookies, python-requests, mechanize

I am working on a Python script that automatically helps me add classes in my school's add-a-class web interface. What I've done so far is, I am able to be authenticated into the website and access the HTML of this add-a-class page. The interface works like so:

[image]

The items under `Status` indicate classes I am currently taking this term.

Under "Add Classes Worksheet", you have a few input 5 digit number called a `CRN` i.e. `34688`. You can type in 10 CRNs at a time.

I was thinking I could simply query the URL with the CRNs that I am interested in adding. Thinking it would be simple, I opened up devtools, and it turns out the POST is a total mess.

Here is the raw form data that I get from the URL it queries under Chrome Dev Tools when I try to add a class in the "Add Classes Worksheet"

```
term_in=201535&RSTS_IN=DUMMY&assoc_term_in=DUMMY&CRN_IN=DUMMY&start_date_in=DUMMY&end_date_in=DUMMY&SUBJ=DUMMY&CRSE=DUMMY&SEC=DUMMY&LEVL=DUMMY&CRED=DUMMY&GMOD=DUMMY&TITLE=DUMMY&MESG=DUMMY&REG_BTN=DUMMY&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=34688&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=ECEC&CRSE=451&SEC=001&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++3.000&GMOD=Standard+Letter&TITLE=Computer+Arithmetic&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=31109&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=BIO&CRSE=141&SEC=073&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++0.000&GMOD=Non+Gradeable+Unit&TITLE=Essential+Biology&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=31099&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=BIO&CRSE=141&SEC=B&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++4.500&GMOD=Standard+Letter&TITLE=Essential+Biology&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=30091&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=ECE&CRSE=493&SEC=001&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++4.000&GMOD=Standard+Letter&TITLE=Senior+Design+Project+III&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=31117&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=BIO&CRSE=141&SEC=001&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++0.000&GMOD=Non+Gradeable+Unit&TITLE=Essential+Biology&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=31525&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=BIO&CRSE=141&SEC=072&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++0.000&GMOD=Non+Gradeable+Unit&TITLE=Essential+Biology&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=30013&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=EXAM&CRSE=080&SEC=001&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++0.000&GMOD=Non+Gradeable+Unit&TITLE=Common+Exam+Period+-+I&MESG=DUMMY&RSTS_IN=&assoc_term_in=201535&CRN_IN=34039&start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016&end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016&SUBJ=ENTP&CRSE=205&SEC=001&LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter&CRED=++++3.000&GMOD=Standard+Letter&TITLE=Ready%2C+Set%2C+Fail&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=34889&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&RSTS_IN=WR&CRN_IN=&assoc_term_in=&start_date_in=&end_date_in=&regs_row=8&wait_row=0&add_row=10&REG_BTN=Submit+Changes
```

From what it appears, it seems in the request, not only do you add the ***new*** CRNs that you want to add, the classes you have added so far ***also*** becomes part of the new request.

Looking deeper into the request, it seems each class, whether it's already a class you currently have in your schedule or it's a class you are adding via the textbox, it follows the following format:

```
assoc_term_in=201535
CRN_IN=34688
start_date_in=03%2F28%2F2016
end_date_in=06%2F11%2F2016
SUBJ=ECEC
CRSE=451
SEC=001
LEVL=Undergraduate+Quarter
CRED=++++3.000
GMOD=Standard+Letter
TITLE=Computer+Arithmetic
MESG=DUMMY
RSTS_IN=
```

Each class has 13 associated query keys and values. I am actually not sure if it's required to re-submit classes that you've already added, and I am willing to perform some tests if necessary.

The request itself is a POST:

```
Request URL:https://school.edu/pls/duprod/bwckcoms.P_Regs 
Request Method:POST 
Status Code:200 OK 
Remote Address:[some IP address]
```

My question is:

1. Can I submit CRNs directly to the textbox avoiding having the re-form the nasty POST request? (i.e. some Python library that does so). Seems like Mechanize is an option, but is it possible to use Requests with Mechanize? I prefer not to re-write all the authentication it took to get into that form page.
2. If the above option is not possible, any ideas how I can re-form the POST request efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to use a `dict` in order to hold all of the information for the post request per [Requests documentation](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). For example your code may look like:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {
  "assoc_term_in":"201535",
  "CRN_IN":"34688",
  "start_date_in":"03%2F28%2F2016",
  "end_date_in":"06%2F11%2F2016",
  "SUBJ":"ECEC",
  "CRSE":"451",
  "SEC":"001",
  "LEVL":"Undergraduate+Quarter",
  "CRED":"++++3.000",
  "GMOD":"Standard+Letter",
  "TITLE":"Computer+Arithmetic",
  "MESG":"DUMMY",
  "RSTS_IN":""
}

r = requests.post("https://school.edu/pls/duprod/bwckcoms.P_Regs", data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.text)
```

Then you can change any of the values that you need to as you would with a normal dictionary. If you wanted to go with #1, one of your options would be to look into something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), however, I personally feel if you already know what the POST request looks like doing something above may be easier.

Comment: Hi Cory. Thanks! There's some information that's a little hard to get for the POST request, such as when the `start_date_in`, `end_date_in` is, or what section a class in, or how the text is formatted, et cetera. I *could* look up that information from querying our term master schedule, but it is a lot of work. I'm going to look into Mechanize. Do you see any differences for Selenium to Mechanize?

Comment: I personally have never used Mechanize, but it seems to be very similar to Selenium. And both should be able to accomplish automating the web  pages. The `start_date_in` and `end_date_in` appear to be url-encoded version of `start_date_in = 03/28/2016` Which can be obtained by using `urllib.quote_plus("03/28/2016")`. Or you should be able to just pass  in the values as `"03/28/2016"` and requests should handle it for you.

Comment: Turns out the already-filled-in-parameters are hidden parameters: http://puu.sh/o15QD/19e417cb58.png Why would they even do this. But anyways, I am making good progress with Mechanize and I think I'll go with that, because there's 0 chance I'll make a mistake in POSTing a wrong parameter.